# GWT Requestfactory: EntityProxy containing List of "InterfaceProxy"

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

Imagine the following situation when using GWT, RequestFactory and JPA.
 The server side:

```
@Entity
public class SuperEmployee implements IsEmployee {...}

@Entity
public class BadEmployee implements IsEmployee {...}

@Entity
public class Supervisor {
List<IsEmployee> employees;
...
}
```

The client side proxies:

```
@ProxyFor(value = Supervisor.class, ...)
public interface SupervisorProxy {...}
```

Now I'd like to have something similar to:

```
@ProxyFor(value = IsEmployee.class, ...)
public interface EmployeerProxy {...}
```

Of course this isn't working, but what would be the solution if I'm not interested in the concrete type on client side and just want to work with the interface methods.

I've read the following articles that might be helpful (but maybe I didn't get the point right):
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html (section "Transportable types").

Thanks for enlightening my Requestfactory knowledge!
Ralf

Answer (score 1):

GWT does not ([yet](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5762)) support `@ProxyFor` pointing to interfaces. This will be possible in 2.7 though.

In the mean time, you have to use a base class on the server-side, or a hierarchy of interfaces on the client-side (possibly with `@ExtraTypes` pointing to the specific interfaces if they're not used directly otherwise)